# Apple's 44x44 touch size minimum; smaller height and longer width acceptable?

Tags: ios, autolayout

So I just submitted my first app.  The design elements (text fields) I am concerned about are 30x90.  Should I have a problem with apple's minimum button size request?

Answer (score 2):

Apple publishes their [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/) to give you as a developer some insight into the best practices used by their own designers. By following the guidelines, you will make your app feel more "familiar" to users. There are definitely situations where it is acceptable to bend or break these rules, and unless your app is outright hard to use, it won't be rejected by Apple.

**Source**: I have multiple apps in the app store, and have broken the Human Interface Guidelines in some small way in each of them.

**tldr; Your app won't be rejected based on your UITextField size.**

Comment: thank you for the swift input.  Would you happen to know what apple is signifying with this 44*44 requirement then?

Comment: @jonpeter It is most likely because it is somewhat hard to tap smaller text fields

Comment: Completely on point with the idea.  Would you believe I need to change my dimensions or hope for the best?

Comment: I think you'll be fine - if it were smaller in both dimensions you might have trouble.